# EntityManger bean not found?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@769f71a9: startup date [Tue Nov 21 15:46:02 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-21 15:46:24.774  INFO 6272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-11-21 15:46:24.922  INFO 6272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-11-21 15:46:24.924  INFO 6272 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-11-21 15:46:25.250  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin;C:\Users\kaleti\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\kaleti\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\kaleti\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;.]
2017-11-21 15:46:25.628  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-11-21 15:46:25.629  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 23087 ms
2017-11-21 15:46:25.986  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-11-21 15:46:25.986  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-21 15:46:25.986  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-21 15:46:25.986  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-21 15:46:25.986  INFO 6272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-11-21 15:46:26.625  WARN 6272 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'statusController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'statusService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'statusService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryImpl': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#340b7ef6' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#340b7ef6': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
2017-11-21 15:46:26.656  INFO 6272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-11-21 15:46:26.788  INFO 6272 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-21 15:46:26.983 ERROR 6272 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter
APPLICATION FAILED TO START***************************

Description:
Field repository in com.learing.demo.StatusService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

**My Code as Below**

```
package com.learing.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

**StatusController class**

```
package com.learing.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class StatusController {

@Autowired
private StatusService statusService;

@RequestMapping("/getEmpStatus")
public List<Employee> GetAllEmployeeStatus(){
    return statusService.GetAllEmpStatus();
}

@RequestMapping("/getEmpStatus/{id}")
public Employee GetAllEmployeeStatus(@PathVariable int id){
    return statusService.GetEmpStatus(id);
}

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, value="/getEmpStatus")
 public void  AddEmployeeStatus(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    statusService.AddEmployeeStatus(employee);

}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value="/getEmpStatus/{id}")
public void  UpdateStatus(@RequestBody Employee employee, @PathVariable int id){
     statusService.UpdateStatus(employee,id);
}
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/getEmpStatus/{id}")
public void  UpdateStatus(@PathVariable int id){
    statusService.DeleteStatus(id);
}
```

}

StatusService class

```
    package com.learing.demo;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class StatusService {

        @Autowired
        public RepositoryImpl repository;

        private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Employee(1, "NSIN253", "Kalpa", "BHS-Mapping", "Mapping doc Completed"), new Employee(2, "NSIN254", "Fareeda", "BHS-Mapping", "Mapping doc Completed"), new Employee(3, "NSIN252", "KrishnaVeni", "BHS-Mapping", "Mapping doc Completed")));


        public List<Employee> GetAllEmpStatus() {
            return employees;
        }

        public Employee GetEmpStatus(int id) {
            return employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getiD() == id).findFirst().get();
        }

        public void AddEmployeeStatus(Employee employee) {
            repository.save(employee);
        }

        public void UpdateStatus(Employee employee, int id) {
            for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
                Employee emp = employees.get(i);
                if (emp.getiD() == id) {
                    employees.set(i, employee);
                }
            }
        }

        public void DeleteStatus(int id) {
            employees.removeIf(emp -> emp.getiD() == id);
        }
    }
```

RepositoryImpl class

```
    package com.learing.demo;

    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface RepositoryImpl extends CrudRepository<Employee,Integer> {

    }
```

application props:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=EmployeeDb
    spring.datasource.username=xxxx
    spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.learing</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Can you show the correct StatusController class, your are showing the wrong class

Comment: Can you please check now I edited question with status Controller.

Comment: Why are you using @Repository annotation? you can omit that if your not handling some special data access exception. see -> https://javabeat.net/spring-annotations-component/

Comment: ok I removed Repository annotation from that class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these from your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data looking for EntityManagerFactory using default bean named entityManagerFactory.

Try using below annotation in your configuration like:

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.learing.demo", entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory")
class Config {}

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in your application.properties configuration. You are using wrong properties

change.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Comment: Yes i modified,still i can see the same issue.